# Unable to initiate model object using variable classname in Yii2

Tags: php, oop, yii2

I want to initiate a model object using a variable model class.

```
        $model = new Role();
//      This works

        $className = "Role";
        $model = new $className();
//      This is not working
//      PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
//      Class 'Role' not found
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means class `Role` (`\Role`) simply does not exist in root namespace.

You should use full class name with namespace, for example:

```
$className = 'app\models\Role';
$model = new $className();
```

You can get full class of any object that extended from [yii\base\Object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html)  with static [className()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html#className%28%29-detail) method:

```
use app\models\Role;

$model = new Role::className();
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. But I was wondering why I have to provide full class name with namespace even when I mentioned the namespace in the controller. $model = new Role(); works well too.

Comment: You mentioned it in namespace, for example `use app\models\Role`, but with this kind of initialization you simply providing string, it's not dependent of declarations in `use` section.

Comment: Updated the information about getting the class name. You can also upvote the answer if it was helpful.